# I use TCPDF how can i print by using livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$view = View::make('Cards.export_card');
$html_content = $view->render();
$pdf::SetTitle('Patient Lists');
$pdf::SetAuthor('SmartTB');
$pdf::SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);
$pdf::SetFontSize('10px');
$pdf::SetY(-15);
$pdf::SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf::SetMargins(10, 18, 8);
$pdf::AddPage('L', 'A4');
$pdf::PageNo();
$pdf::writeHTML($html_content, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf::Output('tb_patient_list_'.time().'.pdf', 'D');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi check Livewire file downloads https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-downloads

```
return response()->streamDownload(function () {
    echo 'CSV Contents...';
}, 'export.csv');
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need the way to pass to streeamDownload func as you see TCPDF generate pdf, the issue comes streeamDownload accept file type eg .pdf while TCPDF already done it before so how to avoid TCPDF from generating file type so that streeamDownload will do it later.

Comment: Save file to storage and use download
```
return response()->download(storage_path('exports/export.csv'));
```